# (Spring Legacy) @Value returns null only in "Specific Config" even though PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer added

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I'm in the process of migrating XML configuration to Java configuration in a legacy Spring project.

To split configurations, I've added *Config.java files.

```java
@Configuration
@Import({AConfig.class, BConfig.class})
public class RootConfig{
    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        // Read properties file and return 
        return propertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class AConfig {
    @Value("${my.value}")
    private String propStr; // null

    @Bean
    public BeanA beanA() {
       // Use propStr
        return new BeanA(propStr);
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class BConfig {
    @Value("${my.value}")
    private String propStr; // value in the .properties file

    @Bean
    public BeanB beanB() {
       // Use propStr
        return new BeanB(propStr);
    }
}
```

Now, I've encountered a problem: `propStr` in AConfig is null, while `propStr` in BConfig holds the value from the .properties file.

Could you please let me know if you are aware of any possible causes for this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to make the problem reproducible in a minimal, but complete set of classes and config files. The devil is in the details, as the saying goes. I think, the root cause might be hidden in the part of your project which you did not share with us here. Ideally, post a Maven project on GitHub. Thank you.